# Elasticsearch Index alias Disappeared when building new index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, alias

The problem we are facing is losing the index alias during the process described below.
We created a cron job that runs and gets new data.
this data is used to build a new index that replaces the old data that we have in our index.
the old index is pointed by an alias.
we are creating the new index, the new mapping, and settings, and index data.
the last step is to change the alias to point to the new index' and delete the old index.
at this point, we can't find the alias and we need to rebuild the index and the alias.

Comment: what does "can't find the alias" mean? what do the logs of your process show? what do the Elasticsearch logs show?

Comment: When I'm trying to replace the  alias to point to the new index the alias could not be found

Comment: is not in `GET _alias` ? what define could not be found ?